# How to send file with telegram api?

Tags: java, telegram-api

I am creating telegram bot, and I need to send a file from my telegam bot to another telegram chat.
Now I am trying to  make it with such request
https://api.telegram.org/bot%s/sendDocument?chat_id=%s&document=%s
I am setting full link to my document like this
C:\Users\User_Name\IdeaProjects\Project_name\src\main\resources\files
When I am tryin to send this request, it's like not sending, and I am not reciving a message in another chat.
Could you help me to resolve this propblem?

Answer (score 0):

Please use some libs for doing these. example : telethon, pyrogram, ptb.

you can use `client.send_file(entity, file)` if you are using telethon.

You may have to download file before sending if its not transload.